# fsDriver type for http api doveadm

Tags: dovecot

i'm searching to use doveadm http api in order to get object from a path so i'm using this curl :

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://10.150.12.11:8080/doveadm/v1' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '[
    [
        "fsGet",
        {
            "fsDriver": "",
            "fsArgs": "",
            "path": "/mnt/a/box/000/000/000/tell.com/554/689/73/"
        },
        "tag2"
    ]
]'
```

but i've that error :

```
doveadm(127.0.0.1): Fatal: fs_init() failed: Unknown fs driver
```

what fs driver types can i use? i don't see anything on documentation https://doc.dovecot.org/admin_manual/doveadm_http_api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In public Dovecot source code there are these fs drivers:

- **posix** communicates with local filesystem
- **dict** uses dict-api for files
- **sis** wraps other fs, can used in sdbox mailbox format for attachments
- **sis-queue** like sis, but postpones deduplication of attachements
- **compress** wraps other fs, (de)compresses files on-the-fly

In paid version of Dovecot there exists fs driver which stores files on cluster (S3) storage.

These `dovedm fs *` methods are useful mainly for this S3 driver used by now paid obox storage plugin.
See https://doc.dovecot.org/admin_manual/dovecot_cluster_architecture/